# Sending mail in .NET

Tags: asp.net, configuration, smtpclient

everyone!
I'm trying to send mail in ASP.NET web-site. I have smtp configuration section in web.config file. How can I configure it to send mail from everyone to everyone?

Comment: You can use SMTPClient class from System.Net.Mail [SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Comment: what do you mean with everyone to everyone?

Comment: Who is 'everyone'? Is it a mail account like everyone@example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have anything in web.config as que SMTP server can be specified in the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613.aspx) constructor.
Then, if you need authentication, you can specify a [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) and the message in a [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) object.
Example:

```
var client = new SmtpClient(smtpHost);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

client.Send(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

`SmtpMail.Send("From","To","Subject","Message");`

Just specify the From and To email addresses and you're set.

SmtpMail can be found in System.Web.Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague.

If you want to send it from "everyone", then you will always need to specify a different FROM parameter for every message.  You do not want to set the FROM value in the .config file.

If you are looking for code examples, I encourage you to check out my site at [www.SystemNetMail.com](http://www.SystemNetMail.com).